# Hyperledger Fabric: how to view debug output of Java chaincode in real-time?

Tags: java, debugging, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

Inside my Java chaincode I have the following lines:

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Working.class);

// chaincode logic...

} catch (Throwable e) {
    // some exception handling...
    logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    // ...more exception handling
}

// ...more chaincode logic...

logger.debug("[HashtagDebug] start invoke() calling " + stub.getFunction()); //deliberately planted debug

// ...and so on so forth...
```

I want to view these chaincode debug in realtime as I run my client app. So far, I have tried

```
docker logs -f --tail 0 <container id of peer node>
```

But there is much debug output, and more importantly, I am unable to find those debug lines that I planted. Am I looking at the wrong place for my debug lines? Where/how should I be looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When chaincode is instantiated on a peer node, the peer node spawns a separate chaincode container named like `dev-(peername)-(chaincodename)-(chaincode version)`.
Check `docker ps` for your actual name. The log of that container contains everything your chaincode writes to stdout/stderr (make sure your logging is configured/enabled properly).

Comment: This looks promising! When I run `docker logs -f --tail 0 <that chaincode container>` I can see output in realtime, but I don't see DEBUG. Can you advise me on how to change the logging level of that particular container?

Comment: Setting the log level works as with every other java program, i.e. it depends on what logging framework you're using. Usually there's a config file where you can set the log levels.

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate the chaincode, peer creates a new docker container to run this chaincode, as mentioned by barnet2k7. This container will have a environment variable called 'CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL'. Usually, this environment variable is set to 'info', so you will only see 'info' level logging. To set this variable to 'debug', you can either manually set the environment variable inside the docker container running the contract, or you can configure this environment variable into the peer with the desired logging level, so every contract instantiated will be set to this level.